# How to build/compile Pwnat

Tags: makefile, build, compilation

I have cloned the source of pwnat from it's github

```
git clone https://github.com/samyk/pwnat
```

But there appears to be no make file in the source

```
# make
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -D LINUX   -c -o socket.o socket.c
make: gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [<builtin>: socket.o] Error 127
```

I want the program pwnat. How to compile it?

Comment: You can't compile C code unless you install a C compiler.  The compiler doesn't come with the code, it's installed separately.  You didn't tell us anything about the system you're using so we can't really advise you.  If you're on Ubuntu for example you can run something like `sudo apt install build-essential` to install all the "essential" tools such as a compiler, make, etc.  BTW, it's a really, **really** bad idea to be doing all this as root.  You should create a user account on your system, without root privileges, and build there.

Comment: Thank you. I misread the error, and didn't realize gcc was not in my environment. Issue solved.